# Problem with setAccount using WSC API gives field not indexed field error

Tags: api, account, event, wsc

I'm trying to create an Event for a specific Account and the WSC api won't let me call setAccount(account). It gives me various errors, the most recent one is

```
Field name provided, Id is not an External ID or indexed field for Account.
```

My sample code is simple, like this:

Field name provided, Id is not an External ID or indexed field for Account

```
        QueryResult queryResults = connection.query("SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'TEST'");
        Account account = (Account) queryResults.getRecords()[0];

        Event event = new Event();
        [ set required fields]
        event.setAccount(account);
        Event[] records = new Event[1];
        records[0] = event;
        SaveResult[] saveResults = connection.create(records);
```

Any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use setWhatId(account.getId());

```
        event.setWhatId(account.getId());
```